# Help identify Venetian headpiece

Tags: identification, italy

So I’ve been trying to find the technical term for these headpieces usually worn during Venetian Carnevale. I’m unsure if they are medieval in origin or a type of turban. What is the difference between the two?
Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The masks of the Venetian carnival are based in the characters of the *Commedia Dell'Arte*, a sort of improvisational theatre born in Italy during the 15th century.

The top photo is a *volto* (a generic mask) with an over-the-top [**chaperon**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaperon_(headgear)), a kind of hoodie that evolved in a hat during the 15th century and it was in fashion all around Western Europe.

The woman below is wearing a Pierrot mask. Pierrots were [*zanni*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zanni), one of the archetypes in the Commedia Dell'Arte. *Zanni* are trickster servants, always more astute and cunning than their masters. Pierrots were described as naïve and lunatic and they wore some of the more crazy or flashy clothes, including **turbans**:

> One or another of a varied range of feathered and unfeathered hats,
> caps, turbans, or even kitchen cauldrons, plumed pouring funnels or
> other non-standard headgear, was actively sported by virtually every
> *zanni*.
>
> M. A. Katritzly, *The Art of Commedia, A Study in the Commedia
> Dell'Arte 1560-1620*, pag. 191